# How to change app color in Samsung S6/Android 5.0 recent apps?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was wondering, how would I change the color of its app menu tab on the Recent Apps screen? Example of apps in recent apps screen attached.

Using Android Studio.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this happens when you use either the new material theme, or the backwards compatible theme provided in the app compat library.

Firstly make sure that your applications theme extends one of the Theme.AppCompat.* themes.

Next set a colourPrimary inside your theme like so:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_brand_red</item>
</style>
```

You can read more about the app compat theme on the [android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).  In particular you might want to read up on the colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent attributes.

Comment: That worked and the dev information was invaluable. Thanks so much!