# How to Get Thumbnails of Recent Apps in Android

Tags: android, screenshot, taskmanager

I'm trying to get thumbnails of recent apps in Android for my app, to help users easily identify and switch to their desired apps.

Is there a way to get thumbnail images?

I've been looking for an API or any method that might help, but all I've found are ways to capture screenshots for apps in the background.

And here's the questions I found:

- [How to take a screenshot of other app programmatically without root permission, like Screenshot UX Trial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462944/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-other-app-programmatically-without-root-permission)
- [How to capture a screenshot of other Android applications from an app without root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271436/how-to-capture-a-screenshot-of-other-android-applications-from-an-app-without-ro)

---

I can't post images :(

Recent apps view is just like the picture in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846354/how-to-change-app-color-in-samsung-s6-android-5-0-recent-apps).

Comment: I do not recall there being an API exposed to provide developers with this information.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, it seems unfeasible... thanks for your comment.